# securing my data without using https

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, https, asp.net-mvc-5

i have build a public facing web site using asp.net mvc -5 web application. now the web site is public so there is no need to provide `https`.but i have a contact us form where users can submit a message along with their name, email AND/OR telephone number. so this info might be considered sensitive in a way or another. but i do not want to implement a security certificate just for this form.so my question if their is a way to secure the contact us form submission without using `https` ? something such as manually encrypt & decry-pt the submitted form ?

Comment: In the end, taking the hit and implementing HTTPS is probably going to be far easier and more straightforward than any other alternative you'll find.

Comment: See also [JavaScript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement some kind of crypto in the client side. See https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441 for libraries that could help.

You'd need to come up with a method of sharing keys between client and server, as well as implement decryption on the server side.

Comment: You can't do it. HTTPS is not only encryption, it's about authentication too.

Comment: @Tom I see your point, is there some method of key exchange that might go some way to ensuring authenticity?

Comment: @Tom implementing HTTPS is going to be easier than all of those I imagine.

Comment: Yes. It's not that hard :) If you want to it correctly, use https for the full website, it will be easier, safer and less error prone. (and, if you have to add more forms, they will be protected too!)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this lib for RSA encryption on the client
https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt
Just generate Public\Private key pair, insert public key into web page (do not insert private key!), encrypt on the client:

```
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setPublicKey(yourpublickeyvariable);
var encrypteddata = encrypt.encrypt(datatosend);
```

Where datatosend is just a concatenation of your param\values (divided by some character to split on the server)

Then on server you can use RSACryptoServiceProvider  to decrypt data

Comment: It will not be secure : the public key will be send using http, so an hacker can replace it with his own public key.

Comment: So what? Did you read OP? If there is no authentication, hacker will just open the form and post it, he doesn't need the key to do that. The question was how to secure users data so nobody but server could read it, not how to make sure that "specific" user has post it. For this scenario  auth is used.

Comment: I know. And your solytion is wrong. With your solution, anyone can replace **yourpublickeyvariable** with his own key, the server will receive garbage and the hacker can decrypt the data. You need to be able to **prove** that  **yourpublickeyvariable** is the public key of the server your talking too and not the public key of a stranger. https with the CA system help for that.

Answer (score -1):

To securely send the contact for, it need two things :

- Encrypt the data before send it **in a way that only your server can decrypt**
- Send it to your server

So, of course, you can encrypt the data using javascript and send it encrypted to your server but **there is not way to do it securely** :

You need a way to **authenticate** your server first. HTTPS do it with the concept of Certificate Authorities. It's not perfect but it's better than nothing.

If you don't want to use https **just for that form** it's ok : just use it for the whole website !
Then, you can send the data securely, protect the privacy of your visitor, prevent ISP to inject ads inside your website and even be faster than http if you use http2.

Comment: >Encrypt the data before send it in a way that only your server can decrypt - That's not true. Asymmetric encryption should be used for that. How do you think HTTPS works from the beginning?

Comment: Asymmetric encryption doesn't solve the problem (and FYI, https use symmetric and asymmetric encryption). Asymmetric encryption doesn't prove that the key you used to encrypt is the correct one. It doesn't **authenticate** the key. https does.